# Why do I need to use Pthread_sigmask in multithreaded programs to assure that a signal is being handled by the set handler?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, signals

I have a multi-threaded program which needs to handle the Linux signal SIGVTALRM sent by a setitimer() every 25ms. However I am confused. I do not know why I need to use the Pthread_sigmask() to block and unblock the signal. Won't the signal be handled anyway when it is sent, regardless of which thread is processing at the given time instant?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

> Won't the signal be handled anyway when it is sent, regardless of which thread is processing at the given time instant?

In a single threaded program, yes. But in a multi-threaded program, POSIX doesn't specify which thread would receive the signal `SIGVTALRM` you send. Hence, [`pthread_sigmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html) is typically used to block the interested signals and handle fetch those signal(s) [`sigwait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html) in a dedicated thread. This is probably the reason why you are using or asked to use `pthread_sigmask()`.

The linked POSIX manual also provides a simple example showing how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I am setting up a timer in the main and then I create the threads, how do I decide which thread should handle it then?

Comment: Common approach is to create a dedicated thread. See [pthread_sigmask()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) where you can find a complete example.

Comment: @lukecam95 Go through this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114678/posix-threads-block-signal-and-unblock to understand how pthread_sigmask works.